# Unable to resume activity with android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error (code 0). How do I fix it?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I have the following problem which occurs on devices with Android Version 5 and 6, but other Android versions do not report such problem. The problem indicates to this line:

```
private var db: SQLiteDatabase = this.writableDatabase
```

However, recently it worked well for all versions and there was no problem. Now it just throws an `SQLiteException: not an error (code 0)`. I tried to search for this problem on Google, but there was no suitable answer for my case. Nevertheless, I tried to apply found answers like adding `READ` and `WRITE` permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml`. C

I cannot find out why it stopped working for Android 5 and 6.

Here is the Stack trace:

```
03-12 23:56:41.542 13600-13600/com.easyapps.cryptnote E/CrashlyticsCore: Failed to execute task.
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:176)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.submitAndWait(CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.java:41)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.handleUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:321)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$6.onUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:301)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:42)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
03-12 23:56:41.543 13600-13600/com.easyapps.cryptnote E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.easyapps.cryptnote, PID: 13600
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.easyapps.cryptnote/com.easyapps.cryptnote.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error (code 0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3028)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3063)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2418)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error (code 0)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeRegisterLocalizedCollators(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setLocaleFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:361)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:218)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:1287)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:268)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
        at com.easyapps.cryptnote.ListDatabase.<init>(ListDatabase.kt:26)
        at com.easyapps.cryptnote.MainActivity.updateNotes(MainActivity.kt:584)
        at com.easyapps.cryptnote.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.kt:123)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1280)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6096)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3011)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3063) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2418) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: Hi, this is not your typical forum, so questions like "hey guys, anybody see this happen before?" won't be accepted well. We want to help you but this is all information we get from you. Where's the stacktrace? What's `this`? What have you tried so far? What's the fully qualified class name for `SQLiteException`? Everything is important and can help figuring out what's wrong. `there was no suitable answer for my case` So what is your case?

Comment: Sorry for the less information, I updated my question and added some details.

Comment: It would be best if you answered all the questions instead of picking just one. For example, what have you tried so far? `I tried to search for this problem on Google` That's good, put a list of links in your questions so we know what we're not supposed to send you, because you already tried. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46916210). Can you debug and check what's `Activity.getResource().getConfiguration().locale`? Try searching for `"nativeRegisterLocalizedCollators" "not an error"`.

Comment: Hello Eugen, thank you very much for your tipp. I am sorry that my question was not too clear for you. But nevertheless, I could fix the problem. Please find the solution I provide as the answer of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Thanks to Eugen Pechanec (answer above), I was able to detect the problem in Locale settings. My application includes Russian, English and German languages and if device language is Russian, then the `Locale.getDefault().language` delivers in Lollipop and Marshmallow (may be in other versions also) the value "русский" which cannot be used for the class `Locale()` and as a result, the `private var db: SQLiteDatabase = this.writableDatabase` crashed. To avoid this value, I implemented the following function in my LanguageSettings class:

```
private fun getLang(): String? {
    return if (Locale.getDefault().language == "русский")
        "ru"
    else
        Locale.getDefault().language
}
```

That's all! It helped to avoid the unresolved value. Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46916210/cannot-get-writable-database-sqliteexception-not-an-error-code-0) contains a similar case, although it did not help me to fix my problem.

Comment: One more thing, could you explain how do you call `getLang()` so `writableDatabase` returns correctly?

Comment: I call it in my `LanguageSettings` class when I need to get persisted data from `PreferenceManager` like this `setLocale(context, getPersistedData(context, getLang()))`. However, I am not sure, how it impacts  `writableDatabase` and what has it with this to do.